# Unhandled Exception: EventArgs in vb.net missing property "handled"

Tags: vb.net

I used the following code:

```
Sub AppStartup()
    AddHandler AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException, 
           Sub(sender As Object, args As UnhandledExceptionEventArgs)
               Dim e = CType(args.ExceptionObject, Exception)
               ShowMessage("Oops...", HandleErr(e), MessageBoxImage.Error)
           End Sub    
End Sub
```

and I don't get the property handled Although it appears this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.unhandledexceptioneventargs.handled) is supposed to be his

Comment: This unhandled exception handler looks correct, and is almost identical to one in my own code, which works.

Answer (score 0):

While your question doesn't really make sense, I'd say its safe to say you are trying to implement an unhandled exception handler.

This article should have all the information you need.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Your link points at XAML article, your question is probably about WinForms.

Are you starting this inside VS? Please note that exception will first be handled by VS, and then by this handler. When you run as a standalone executable, it should work as expected. You don't need to set any `e.Handled` to anything.